# Does the Django REST Framework have something like a UML Component Diagram?

Tags: django

I have an idea of how I can use DRF to enhance an existing Django application.  I see in the documentation how the DRF can interact with Djanco routers and even create a custom router.

In most MVC Frameworks the router can route requests from the controller to Model services or to View services.  But in Django I read that there really isn't a "controller" per se and the Views ride on the Django infrastructure to connect to the models.

If I wanted to follow a Microservices architecture the the DRF to change the orchestration of dataflow between the views and the models it would seem logical that I would modify the router(s) as the DRF documentation hints at.

A UML Component Diagram or Data Flow Diagram or Sequence Diagram would help a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but there is this Python module to create UML diagram from an existing Python program: https://pygraphviz.github.io/ . Also, consider Django ninja over DRF, might be more flexible and simple to edit routers and will easily generate schema - sorry if this is not your question.

Comment: Thanks that does help a bit.  What I am looking for is how I can use a Microservices architecture on Django so I can have shared services instead of the one to one View <-> Model flows.  For example, I wuld like to have a shared service that can be called from any view before data is saved to the model.  Further, I would be interested in dynamic orchestration of services so I can add a service in a sequence without having to shut down and modify a view or several views.